# button not getting displayed in honeyconb

Tags: android, button, android-3.0-honeycomb

this is my custom "change password" dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:text="Old Password " android:id="@+id/textViewOldPwd"
                android:isScrollContainer="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/editTextOPwd" android:singleLine="true" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:text="New Password " android:id="@+id/textView0"
                android:isScrollContainer="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/editTextNPwd" android:singleLine="true" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:text="Confirmation " android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:isScrollContainer="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/editTextCPwd" android:singleLine="true" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <Button android:text="Change Password" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/btnChangePwd"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".50" />
            <Button android:text="Cancel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/btnCancelPwd"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".50" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The last two buttons btnChangePwd and btnCancelPwd are getting displayed properly in wildfire (android 2.2) but not in galay tab (android 3.1). it just comes as empty space.

other parts of code are:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
final View passwordDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.newpassword, null);
dialog.setContentView(passwordDialog);


<resources>
    <style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, I think that it is a bug in the 2.2. Wildfire, because the way the xml is specified, those buttons should never show up.  The problem line is:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:stretchColumns="1">
```

See the part about the layout_height?  That means this is going to fill the parent and the buttons that come next will be pushed off the screen.  In the emulator, that is exactly what happens no matter what version I use.  Changing that to wrap_content make the buttons appear.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. my bad. but surprisingly height="fill_parent" works perfectly for a dialog, but not an activity. (This change did not fix my issue!)

Comment: Wow, that is strange, it fixes it for me on the emulator for 3.2 in a dialog. If I leave fill_parent, no buttons appear, if I change to wrap_content, they appear.  I guess I will have to try it on my Tab to see why it does not fix it there.